# Android 4.4+ How do apps like MightyText and AirDroid send SMS?

Tags: android, sms

Both of these applications allow you to send SMS on your desktop/through a web browser as if it's coming from your phone (it really is coming from your phone). My question is:

How do they automatically send SMS through the Default SMS App (Messenger) without any user interaction (in the background/discretely) on Android 4.4?

Answer (score 1):

Any app that has SEND_SMS permission can send the message using SmsManager.
The default SMS app is responsible for writing the sent messages to the sms provider.
Apps like mightytext, mobitexter which allow to send sms from web sends the message using SmsManager and in 4.4+ the default SMS app takes care of writing the sent messages to the sms provider.
For more details you can read http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html
PS: I work on a similar app mobitexter.net

Answer (score 0):

MightyText has permission to send sms messages. So the app is not using the default sms app, but sending the messages using the Android API.

Messages send by the app are added to the default messaging SQL database on the phone. Because of that it will look like the default app has send them.